# Schedule a batch at certain hours

Tags: batch-file, salesforce, apex, schedule

I made a schedulable batch that I want to run at certain hours, let's say 6, 12 and 18. I'm writting those hours in a custom setting CS_Schedule__c. How can I call that CS from Apex and get the hours?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en_US) is a page outlining how to retrieve Custom Settings in Apex depending on if it's a List or Hierarchy Custom Settings.

As far as scheduling, you can do that in Apex if you wish, like so:

```
classToSchedule schCls = new classToSchedule();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Name of Job', sch, schCls);
```

The sch string is a CRON expression that will represent the time it runs. Check out this [CRON expression builder](http://www.cronmaker.com/) for more info. Instead of using numbers you would build that string from data in custom setting.